# need help calling a variable outside of event handler parenthesis

Tags: vb.net

i have this code

```
Private Sub moAccounts_PositionUpdate(ByVal poPositions As A4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateList) Handles moAccounts.PositionUpdate

    ' Display the position details.
    For Each oUpdate As AccountList.PositionUpdateList.PositionUpdate In poPositions

       'code here

    Next

    End sub
```

What I want to do is call the sub above from within another sub.  The problem is the variable poPositions appears nowhere else in the code. I think it is an array of data fed by the API. I need to find out how to get the data from the server API in the event handler parenthesis so I can then call the sub above and update the data

i have tried this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    udate()

End Sub

Private Sub udate()

    Dim poPositions As A4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateList

    For Each oUpdate As AccountList.PositionUpdateList.PositionUpdate In poPositions

       'code here
    Next

End Sub
```

the code compiles, but when i run the code the code stops executing and shows an error underlining poPositions

```
    For Each oUpdate As AccountList.PositionUpdateList.PositionUpdate In **poPositions**

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*
```

if ByVal poPositions As A4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateList works inside the event handler parenthesis, it has to work outside. the issue is (i guess) in the syntax

this obviously doesnt work

```
Dim poPositions As A4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateList
```

i tried this *outside* the parenthesis:

```
ByVal poPositions As A4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateList
```

but that generates an error at ByVal

so i am stuck as to how to ... define (?) ... poPositions. what is the term to put in front of poPositons to get it to grab the data when the statement is placed **outside** the event handler parenthesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not as simple as moving code around. When the moAccounts_PositionUpdate event is triggered, the server has the data that needs to be passed to the handler and provides it. If you don't have this information, you have to create it from scratch or re-use a copy of that information that the server provided in an earlier call to moAccounts_PositionUpdate (unless the server provides a way for you to *request* a copy of that information on demand). One thing you could do is store a copy of the last poPositionsValue that was provided by the server. However, this will only work if moAccounts_PositionUpdate occurs *before* anyone clicks on the button. If the moAccounts_PositionUpdate event never runs, you won't have any data and the button will again give you an error.

```
Private cachedPoPositions As A4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateList
Private Sub moAccounts_PositionUpdate(ByVal poPositions As A4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateList) Handles moAccounts.PositionUpdate
    ' Save for re-use later
    cachedPoPositions = poPositions
    ' Display the position details.
    For Each oUpdate As AccountList.PositionUpdateList.PositionUpdate In poPositions
       'code here
    Next
End sub

Private Sub udate()
    For Each oUpdate As AccountList.PositionUpdateList.PositionUpdate In cachedPoPositions
       'code here
    Next
End Sub
```

What would be better is if you could find some function that would *request* the current information from the API when it is needed. For example:

```
Private Sub udate()
    Dim poPositions = moAccounts.GetPositionUpdateList()
    For Each oUpdate As AccountList.PositionUpdateList.PositionUpdate In poPositions
       'code here
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. yes, that is the idea, to get the most recent position list. they way they have it, when the form loads 'moAccounts_PositionUpdate' runs, but that's it. i was hoping to figure out how to get that event to fire on demand as the data i need to know (what the current position is) emanates from 'ByVal poPositions As A4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateList'. and, yes, i could store the original data that first comes in, but to redisplay it doesnt help because i will need to know what the current position is, not the one in the first place. thanks again

Comment: Then you need to either look at the bottom block of code and see if you can find a function to take the place of "GetPositionUpdateList" that will request the current version. Or you need to use the first block of code and find a way to force the API to fire the event on demand. Without more information about the API I don't think we can help you further. Whatever Form_Load is doing that forces the event to fire might be a path to explore though. Perhaps a new instance of moAccounts can be created every time the button is clicked to force it to trigger the event each time or something.

Comment: there is nothing else in the code that refers to poPositions As ... it just shows up in this little sub. the only way to dig deeper would be to crack open the API dll file, but that is probably too extreme. my thinking is there has to be a way to just call the event as is, eg 'call Private Sub moAccounts_PositionUpdate(ByVal poPositions As A4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateList) Handles moAccounts.PositionUpdate' just simply re-run the event. it cant be that complicated. there must be a way to re-run the event. at least that certainly would be the easiest solution. thank you for all your help!

Comment: If you go into a sub (your button click code, for example) and type "moAccounts" and add a "." at the end, a list of everything the API can do should pop up (the moAccounts piece of it at least). Hopefully that will help you guess at some useful things you could try with the API. If anything looks like a way to force the event to re-run or a way to refresh or re-acquire the PositionUpdateList value, that'd be worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem:

```
Dim poPositions As A4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateList
```

You declare the variable but you never set it.

Comment: yes, but how to set it is the problem i guess ... 'Dim poPositions As A4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateList = ???' ? its frustrating to know that the data comes in when the event runs, but i cant figure out how to 're-run' the event on demand to update. the only way i can do it is to close the app and reload the form, etc, which of course isnt what i want. i want to 'click' a button and either rerun the event and get the data, or have some other way to get the data that is present inside the event handler parenthesis outside of it into another variable i can work with. could be a syntax issue?